# Functional equation of Rankin-Selberg zeta function

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms, l-functions

Can someone explain to me where come from the functional equation (1.6) in this  [article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1007.4310v2.pdf) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that the functional equation appears in the cited work of Rankin and Selberg (independently).

For a slightly longer (classical) answer, suppose $f(z)$ is the weight $12$ cusp form on $\text{SL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$ whose coefficients are the Ramanujan $\tau$ function. And let $E(z,s)$ be Selberg's Eisenstein series
$$
\zeta(2s) \sum_{\gamma \in \Gamma_\infty \backslash \text{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})} \text{Im} (\gamma z)^s.
$$
Then the functional equation $s \mapsto 1-s$ of the Eisenstein series is a classical computation (which is easily searchable).
Computing the Petersson inner product gives the Rankin-Selberg zeta function associated to $f$ in the sense that
$$
\langle \lvert f \rvert^2 y^{12}, E(\cdot,s)\rangle = \frac{\Gamma(s + 11)}{(4\pi)^{s + 11}} \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{\tau(n)^2}{n^{s+11}}.
$$
In this form, the functional equation of the Eisenstein series gives exactly the functional equation of the Rankin-Selberg zeta function.

For more on Eisenstein series, I would recommend looking at Diamond and Shurmans [A first course in modular forms](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387232294). For more on Selberg's Eisenstein series, I recommend looking at Goldfeld's [Automorphic forms on $\text{GL}(n, \mathbb{R})$](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/number-theory/automorphic-forms-and-l-functions-group-glnr), or even at the original papers of Ranking and Selberg. Each of these includes a discussion of the Rankin-Selberg convolution and zeta function.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and for the references

Comment: You write out the product of the Fourier expansions in the Petersson inner product. The Eisenstein series allows you to "unfold" the integral  (this is a commonly used term). Performing the resulting x integration isolates the $a (n)^2$ terms. This is a bit dense, and if you'd like I can comment more on it later  (when I'm in front of a computer).

Comment: Yes, it will be helpful.

Comment: Perhaps [these notes](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/v/basic_rankin_selberg.pdf) give a reasonable overview. The topic is the proof on page 3. A bit more can be found on page 3 of [this other note](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~schmid/articles/gl2pairings.pdf), which describes "unfolding" a bit more.

Comment: Thank you again  for the references.

Comment: @Med  See also [this post](http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/read.php?5,1308891,1344176#msg-1344176) where I tried to generalize to some congruence subgroups (you'll need more work for obtaining what we really want : the Rankin-Selberg convolution for $M_k(\Gamma_0(N), \chi(N))$

Comment: @user1952009, Merci pour votre commentaire.

Answer (score 0):

You can check Cogdell's notes, say https://people.math.osu.edu/cogdell.1/ictp-www.pdf

For your case, you also need to calculate the local gamma factor at the infinity place, which is quite standard.

Comment: Those kind of things are above my level. The adelic viewpoint $\int_{k^\times / A^\times} f(a) d^\times a$ is really too abstract for me, and I need to start with an explanation of what it means in the simpler modular case ($GL_2$) before generalizing to $GL_n$ @Med